# How to automatically generate the predictor function associated with a formula?

Tags: r, functional-programming, regression, metaprogramming

Consider, for example, the following regression

```
linear.model <- lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data = my.data)
```

...and the following closure

```
Y <- local({
    beta <- coef(linear.model)
    function(X1, X2) cbind(1, X1, X2, X1 * X2) %*% beta
})
```

This closure `Y` implements the *predictor function*<sup>1</sup>

> *Y* = *X* · *β*

encoded by the formula used to define `linear.model`<sup>2</sup>.

One could readily turn the RHS of the earlier assignment to `Y` into a factory function:

```
make.predictor.function.xyz <- function (model) {
    beta <- coef(model)
    function(X1, X2) cbind(1, X1, X2, X1 * X2) %*% beta
}
```

...and use this factory to define `Y`, like this:

```
Y <- make.predictor.function.xyz(linear.model)
```

---

Unfortunately, `make.predictor.function.xyz` works only for models with a formula of the form

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2
```

(I tacked the suffix `.xyz` at the end of the name `make.predictor.function.xyz` to hint at this lack of generality.)

On the other hand, all the information needed to implement the `make.predictor.function.xyz` factory is encoded in the `y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2` formula, available through `formula(linear.model)`.

This suggests the possibility of implementing a generalized `make.predictor.function` factory to create predictor functions for a much broader class of models (for example, all models returned by `lm`).

---

**Q:** How could one implement such a generalized `make.predictor.function`?

Since one can use the `formula` function to recover from a model the formula used to define it<sup>3</sup>, this problem reduces to that of generating a predictor function using as inputs

1. a formula
2. a compatible set of coefficients

(This is the case at least for models generated with `lm`.  For those generated with `glm`, for example, one may need additional parameters to automatically generate the associated predictor function.)

---

A more concrete version of this question would this:  How would one generate the function

```
function(X1, X2) cbind(1, X1, X2, X1 * X2) %*% beta
```

...using *only* the `linear.model` object created above as input?  And, **importantly**, can this method be generalized, beyond `linear.model`, to *any* model returned by `lm`?

---

I am aware of `stats::predict.lm`, but AFAICT, this function returns point predictions for a new set of input values.  What I want is a function `make.predictor.function` that returns another *function*.

---

**UPDATE**

I tested out AES idea of implementing a predictor function as a wrapper around `stats::predict`.  Below I show what I did, along with some benchmarks.

```
# simulate some data
df <- local({
    set.seed(0)
    n <- 1000
    x1 <- rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    x2 <- rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    err <- rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    y <- 1 + 2 * x1 + 3 * x2 + 4 * x1 * x2 + err
    data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, y = y)
})

linear.model <- lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data = df)

Y1 <- local({
    beta <- coef(linear.model)
    function(X1, X2) cbind(1, X1, X2, X1 * X2) %*% beta
})

Y2 <- function(X1, X2) {
    predict(linear.model,
            data.frame(x1 = X1, x2 = X2),
            type = "response")
}

set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
x2 <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Y1(x1, x2), Y2(x1, x2))
## Unit: microseconds
##        expr      min       lq       mean   median        uq      max neval
##  Y1(x1, x2)   28.375   29.720   32.11508   32.661   33.4845   49.939   100
##  Y2(x1, x2) 1160.826 1173.035 1241.20415 1190.467 1208.9730 2776.199   100
```

(I.e. `Y1` is ~40x faster than `Y2`.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I'm using the verbose term "predictor function", rather than just "predictor", to avoid confusion with the meaning of "predictor" as the summands in a regression formula (as in, "the predictors in the formula `y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2`,  are the terms `x1`, `x2`, and `x1 * x2`".)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> In fact, the expressions `as.vector(linear.model$fitted.values)` and `as.vector(Y(my.data$x1, my.data$x2))` should be identical, modulo floating-point-arithmetic-related differences.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> Thanks to lmo for this pointer.</sup>

Comment: Extracting the formula from an `lm` object can be accomplished with `formula`.  For example, `temp <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris); formula(temp)`.

Comment: @lmo: thanks!  I'll edit my post to include this information.

Comment: Are you interested in building the prediction function yourself? Because if not, you could of course make a function that returns a function that wraps the `predict` generic. Then you would have the desired behaviour.

Comment: @AEF: my main concern with that approach is one of efficiency, but I should do some benchmarking before ruling it out.

Comment: Efficiency in terms of speed or in terms of memory? I doubt that it will be much slower than a manual version, but it could allocate quite a bit of memory. See for example http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/03/using-closures-as-objects-in-r/ section "Problems with R closures". Anyway I am interesed in your profiling!

Comment: `fit <- lm(..., x = TRUE); fit$x %*% coef(fit)`

Comment: @AEF: my initial tests confirm that the wrapper is 20x slower than the direct implementation.  I'll post a concrete example, together with the benchmark results, shortly.

Comment: @AEF: I posted some benchmarks.  Please let me know if my implementation of your idea is not what you had in mind.

Comment: I would recommend doing this via `model.matrix` and linear algebra: `model.matrix(formula,data) %*% coef(fit)`

Comment: @rawr: AFAICT, `fit$x %*% coef(fit)` just returns basically the same thing as `fit$fitted.values` (modulo numeric error).  This is not what I'm asking for.

Comment: @BenBolker: the benchmark results for that solution are almost identical to those I reported for AEF's solution.  What I need to do now is get a hold of the source for `model.matrix`.  I'm sure that'll tell me how to implement what I'm after.

Comment: @kjo: Yes, that is exactly what I had in mind. Thanks for posting the benchmark! Interesting to see that it is indeed that slow, I would never have guessed. I also just tried constructing the `data.frame` outside the function which of course makes it a bit faster, but still much slower than the "manual" solution.

Comment: Well, I was wrong.  The source for `model.matrix` ends up invoking `.External2(C_modelmatrix, ...)`, which does what I'm after, so no dice...